# Getting error while parsing json in react native

Tags: javascript, android, fetch, react-native, react-native-ios

this is my json response

```
    {
    "sessid": "some_value",
    "session_name": "some_vvalue",
    "token": "some_vvalue",
    "user": {
        "uid": "12125",
        "name": "some_vvalue",
        "mail": "some_vvalue",
        "theme": "",
        "signature": "",
        "signature_format": "filtered_html",
        "created": "1486476553",
        "access": "1489577945",
        "login": 1489585116,
        "status": "1",
        "timezone": "Asia/Kolkata",
        "language": "",
        "picture": "0",
        "data": false,
        "roles": {
            "2": "authenticated user"
        },
        "rdf_mapping": {
            "rdftype": ["sioc:UserAccount"],
            "name": {
                "predicates": ["foaf:name"]
            },
            "homepage": {
                "predicates": ["foaf:page"],
                "type": "rel"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

i just want to get first three values that is session_name,session_id and token, And i am getting this value during post request,here is my code for parsing.

```
 async onPressLogin() {
    try {

      loaderHandler.showLoader("Please wait!!!");
      let response = await fetch(
        'http://some_url/api/user/login', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'X-CSRF-Token': this.state.token,
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            username: this.state.name,
            password: this.state.password,
          })
      });
      let responseText = await response.text();
      let responseJson = await response.json();

      if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300){


         await AsyncStorage.setItem(SESSION_TOKEN, responseJson.token);
         await AsyncStorage.setItem(SESSION_NAME,responseJson.session_name);
         await AsyncStorage.setItem(SESSION_ID,responseJson.sessid);

         Alert.alert('Store Token', 'Session Token'+responseJson.token)

      ///  Alert.alert('Server response', responseJson)
        loaderHandler.hideLoader();
        Actions.Documents();
      }
      else {
        loaderHandler.hideLoader();
        let error = responseText;

        Alert.alert('Login', error)
      }
    } catch(errors) {
      loaderHandler.hideLoader();
      Alert.alert('Login_server', errors)
    loaderHandler.hideLoader();
    }

   }
```

I am trying to store these three values in async storage for further use. Please help me tried everything but could not solve the error. Let me know if you will need any other code. Thanks

This is the error which i am getting 
    TypeError: expected dynamic type'string',but had type'object'

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: TypeError: expected dynamic type'string',but had type'object'

Comment: Add the complete stacktrace to the question.

Comment: I think error is this line "let responseJson = await response.json();' when m commenting this line it is not showing any error, but if iwill comment this line then how i parse the success response

Comment: Try logging the `responseJson` variable. And see what do you get in it.